# `FFmpeg` `segment_time` inserts blank frames at the beginning of segment

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using the following command to cut videos in parts.
I need parts to be less than passed max_length param, I do not need precise cuts.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov \
-segment_time 20 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 input_%d.mov
```

Every first part video file cut by `ffmpeg` is not 20s, but 20.5s long. And it has several black frames at the beginning inserted by `ffmpeg`.

I don't mind having 19.5s long parts if that is needed because of keyframes. But I need to get rid of those black frames at the beginning so that videos cut in parts could be concatenated in a single video later without any troubles.

Could you give me an advice?

---

Upd:

There were no black frames in an original video which was 23 seconds long.
I made a cut setting 12 as a segment length.

I also had to add `-c copy` because I would like to keep original quality if that's possible.

Leading black frames were added after a cut to part 1 which is 12 seconds long.

Trailing black frames were added after a cut to part 2 which is 10 seconds long.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zo8evta3w1xho3o/AABpTB3w3CuPa1WcghkSIVfna?dl=0

The command used was

```
ffmpeg -y -i /Users/nt/Desktop/cut/AAL_CrSlowMo_041413_1.mov -c copy -segment_time 12 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 /Users/nt/Desktop/cut/AAL_CrSlowMo_041413_1_%d.mov
```

Here's output of `ffmpeg`:
https://gist.github.com/nmtitov/ad102539f95fa03b95f10a46f8d99663

Comment: Show the full log and share the first segment, if you can.

Comment: @Mulvya could you take a look at the update?

Comment: Which player are you testing in? Your segments have no black frames at head or tail. Checked by playback in VLC and Potplayer, and by extracting frames to images using ffmpeg.

Comment: Quicktime player...

Comment: Is there a way to make Quicktime play it right?

Comment: Output segments to `.ts` and then rewrap those to `.mov`.